# Cannot change individiual core frequency on Raspberry with cpufreq-set

Tags: pi-3b+, measuring

I used to use cpufreq-set to change the cores' frequency individually on my RPi 3B+, but I noticed that recently I cannot do it anymore. The effect of:

sudo cpufreq-set -c 2 -f 1400000

is the change of frequency in all 4 cores.

Any hint?

Comment: Did you upgrade the operating system? I have never tried to do this on a Pi, so I'm not familiar with the process, but I'd like to know if we can rule out the possibility of it being a problem with newer software.

Comment: Yes, I have a new version now. I noticed that there are more frequencies available now. It might be for the same reason.

Comment: Could you edit your post and include the OS version you were running before you noticed this problem, as well as your current OS version?

Comment: It might also be good to know what frequencies were available before and the ones you see now.